# asp mvc code first update model without lossing data

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I have the following `DbContext`:

```
namespace Tasks.Models
{
    public class TaskDBInitializer :  DropCreateDatabaseIfModelChanges<TasksContext>
    {
        protected override void Seed(TasksContext context)
        {
            var projects = new List<Projects>
            {
                new Projects{ Title="proTitle", Describe="proDescribe" },
            };
            projects.ForEach(p => context.Projects.Add(p));
            context.SaveChanges();
            base.Seed(context);;
        }
    }

    public class TasksContext : DbContext
    {
        public TasksContext() : base("name=TaskDB")
        {
            Database.SetInitializer(new TaskDBInitializer());
        }
        public DbSet<Task> Task { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Projects> Projects { set; get; }
    }
}
```

I now want to add another model but don't want to lose data that exists within the current database.

How can I add a model to my `DbContext` without losing data?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using `DropCreateDatabaseIfModelChanges<TContext>` as your `IDatabaseInitializer<TContext>` use [`MigrateDatabaseToLatestVersion<TContext,TMigrationsConfiguration>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.entity.migratedatabasetolatestversion-2?view=entity-framework-6.2.0) which will determine changes within your `DbContext` then update your existing database to be compatible.

**Here is an example of how to implement the `MigrateDatabaseToLatestVersion` initializer:**

```
namespace Tasks.Models
{
    public sealed class TaskDBConfiguration : DbMigrationsConfiguration<TasksContext>
    {
        public TaskDBConfiguration()
        {
            AutomaticMigrationsEnabled = true;
            AutomaticMigrationDataLossAllowed = false;
        }

        protected override void Seed(TasksContext context)
        {
            var projects = new List<Projects>
            {
                new Projects { Title = "proTitle", Describe = "proDescribe" },
            };

            projects.ForEach(p => context.Projects.Add(p));

            context.SaveChanges();

            base.Seed(context);
        }
    }

    public class TasksContext : DbContext
    {
        public TasksContext() : base("name=TaskDB")
        {
            Database.SetInitializer<TasksContext>(
              new MigrateDatabaseToLatestVersion<TasksContext, TaskDBConfiguration>()
            );
        }

        public DbSet<Task> Task { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Projects> Projects { set; get; }
    }
}
```

Comment: Then, could I use "Seed" in this form.?

Comment: It made an error: Your project table is exist. Did I do some things wrong?

Comment: I updated my solution to include the Seed method and moved the designation of the initializer back into the DbContext constructor. Do you still receive the error? If so, can you add it to the comments.

Comment: I have "System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: 'There is already an object named 'Projects' in the database.'" Error.

Comment: Try running `Add-Migration Initial -IgnoreChanges` in the [Package Manager Console](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/tools/package-manager-console#opening-the-console-and-console-controls). Make sure the project containing the DbContext is selected as the "Default project" before running the command.